# How to programatically get SD Card CID via Delphi or Lazarus in Windows OS?

Tags: delphi, sd-card, lazarus

In this case I want to read SD Card CID number in Delphi or Lazarus in the Windows OS.Notice that CID is a 16 bytes number(32 digits in hex format). Is It possible to help me?

Comment: I don't know how to do it through Delphi.   But you will call the DeviceIOControl API.    Here is a .NET example http://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/12/read-secure-digital-sd-card-serial.html

Comment: @RobertLove, your link doesn't contain source code. I want source code for a native language like delphi, C++, freepascal and so on.

Comment: A quick google of "DeviceIOControl Delphi" turned up several source code examples. This, combined with the MSDN documentation should give you pretty much everything you need.

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri Hence the reason I posted a comment instead of an answer, I was just adding a bit of information that may help.